# How to change the font for biblatex acronyms

Tags: fonts, biblatex, acronyms, small-caps

I have a bibliography in `biblatex` and I want to use different fonts than *Computer Modern*, namely *Lato* & *Bitstream Charter*. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[defaultsans, scale=0.9]{lato}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{
  shannon,
  author = {Shannon, C. E.},
  title = {A mathematical theory of communication},
  journal = {SIGMOBILE Mob. Comput. Commun. Rev.},
  issue_date = {January 2001},
  volume = {5},
  number = {1},
  month = jan,
  year = {2001},
  issn = {1559-1662},
  pages = {3--55},
  numpages = {53},
  url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/584091.584093},
  doi = {10.1145/584091.584093},
  acmid = {584093},
  publisher = {ACM},
  address = {New York, NY, USA},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This results in the following output after running `biber` and `pdflatex`:

[image: example]

The red arrows indicate my problem: Because *Bitstream Charter* has no actual small caps, LaTeX simply shrinks the characters for acronyms like `ISSN` and I don't like how this looks. So my question is: How can I change the font such that acronyms are simply displayed regularly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to change the macro `\mkbibacro`. Its original definition is

```
\newcommand*{\mkbibacro}[1]{%
  \ifcsundef{\f@encoding/\f@family/\f@series/sc}
    {#1}
    {\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}}
```

so a somewhat brute-force approach (replacing small caps with "typeset as-is" (here: capitals) for all fonts) would be

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibacro}[1]{#1}
```

A better way is to trick `biblatex` into thinking that Mathdesign/Bitstream Charter doesn't feature small caps. Add the following to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\mkbibacro}[1]{%
  \csundef{\f@encoding/mdbch/\f@series/sc}%
  \ifcsundef{\f@encoding/\f@family/\f@series/sc}
    {#1}
    {\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Note: The "font shorthand" `mdbch` for Mathdesign/Bitstream Charter can be detected by adding `\show\rmdefault` to the OP's example.

Comment: Would you mind to clarify why "trick" is better? A "brute-force" approach seems shorter.

Comment: @mlt The brute-force method will always result in capitals, even if you switch to a font that features small caps.

Comment: @lockstep Thank you. I actually was looking for lowercase "doi" in a regular font and I settled on `\renewcommand*{\mkbibacro}[1]{\MakeLowercase{#1}}` and `\urlstyle{same}`.

Comment: Why `\renewcommand` and not just `\csundef{\f@encoding/\f@family/\f@series/sc}%` after the font declaration?